# Get line that have less than 50 digit character and display the line number from a csv file

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

as the title suggest.
How can i get the information that in what line (line number) i have less than 50 character in a csv file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, i find the answer elsewhere, so this is the solution that found which work pretty great for me

```
awk 'length($0) < 50 { print NR ":" $0 }' filename.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

May it help u, Have you tried this: awk 'length>50{print NR,$0}' path-to-file

Comment: i try it, it just print the whole file in terminal.. i have a 65,000 line csv file, do you have other suggestion?